# How do I get my web images to display consistently from laptop to desktop and vise versa?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, export, resolution

To be clear: I am not looking for "save for web" answers. I am having a quality issue from laptop to desktop and I fear its my resolution settings—it's driving me nuts.

I am creating vector images on my laptop with CC that contain text to be used in multiple ways (email, website, google slides, etc). I have exported at 1x, 2x via Illustrator and Photoshop (via smart graphic) as well as saving for web for both. I have a changed my settings and exported multiple times to test quality.

Results:
All of my images when previewed on laptop are blurry. 
All of my images when previewed on desktop are crisp.
When I view a side by side of my logo preview on both, the laptop is blurry and the desktop is crisp.
ALL of my images, on laptop and desktop, inserted into the aforementioned context are blurry.
When I upload my images to photobucket for testing in aforementioned context, ALL images are crisp.
When I insert those photobucket links into my layouts, ALL images are blurry.
When I upload and send all images via Google products, ALL  images are blurry!

Here is a sample of what I am seeing. Do you see the difference in quality?
Same image, screenshot from laptop left vs screenshot from desktop right.

[image]

I'm going mad! What am I missing?
First time laptop user :: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

Answer (score 1):

You're giving no hint from which app you took the screenshots. PS or AI? Paths or pixels?

For pixels, make sure you compare at the same pixel scales (best 100%). It looks like you're scaling up the non-retina version to match sizes and then wonder why it gets blurry. You'd have to compare the 2x version on retina with the 1x version on non-retina. The quality should then be much higher on retina.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are on a retina macbook. I don't know what specific 'google' product you might be using, but it's likely that that product isn't handling retina screens for you...so you are essentially seeing the exact same images on both devices, but your browser is 'blurring' it on the retina screen to enlarge it 2x in the browser for you.